# How to retrieve the data from database from listview click

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I want to show the data from database for editing,on listview item click.on which item user click,it show the data in editbox in next activity.so that user can update it,and also i want onlongClick user can delete that particular data.in listview i'am displaying only name.,nt the contact number and message..,how to display them too in the edittext in smsSend activity..?

Campaign_Details.java

```
    package com.example.smscampaign;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

import com.example.second.Scale;




import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Campaign_Details extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
     Cursor c;
     private DataBaseHelp mdb;
        private ListView lvMessage;
        private ArrayList<Bean> alSentMessage;
        private Demo adapter;
        public String ADD_TO_NAME="toname";
 ListView listview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_demostration);
        TextView txt1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);
         listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
         PackageInfo pInfo = null;
         try 
         {
            pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
         } 
         catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
        txt1.setText(pInfo.versionName);

        TextView txt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textnum1);
  /*      mdb=new DataBaseHelp(this);
        alSentMessage=new ArrayList<Bean>();
        lvMessage=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        c=mdb.fetchAllContacts();
        c.moveToFirst();
        Log.d("cursor",""+c.getCount());
        while(c.moveToNext()){
          Bean mb=new Bean();
          Log.e("ColumnIndex",""+c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelp.KEY_NAME));
          mb.setToName((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelp.KEY_NAME))));
          alSentMessage.add(mb);
        }
        adapter=new Demo(Campaign_Details.this,alSentMessage);
        lvMessage.setAdapter(adapter);*/
      //  String [] values1= data.split("\n");
       // int t = values1.length;
       // txt.setText(Integer.toString(t));

       // String[] values = new String[] { data };
        DataBaseHelp info= new DataBaseHelp(this);
        info.open();
        //ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        //list1= info.getData();
        //String[] values= list1.;
        ArrayList<String> arr = info.getData();
                final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i <  arr.size(); i++) {
                    list.add(arr.get(i));
                }
                adapter = new Demo(this, list);
              //  Demo.setNotifyOnChange(true);


                listview.setAdapter(adapter);


       listview.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Intent i= new Intent("com.example.second.SMSSEND");
        String mName= SmsSend.ed1.getText().toString();
       String mScale=SmsSend.ed2.getText().toString();
       String mContatcs= SmsSend.conct.toString() ;
      String st=   information.getText().toString();
        long lt= Long.parseLong(st);
        DataBaseHelp e= new DataBaseHelp(this);
        e.open();
        e.updateEntry(lt,mName,mScale,mContatcs);

        e.close();  
         startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nextPage:
            Intent i= new Intent(Campaign_Details.this,SmsSend.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        }
        return true;
    }




}
```

SmsSend.java

```
import java.util.Map;

import com.example.smscampaign.MainActivity.MyAdapter;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsSend extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    BroadcastReceiver smsSentReciver, smsSentDelivery;
    static EditText ed1, ed2;
    static int ResultCode = 12;
    static ArrayList<String> sendlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    Button b1, b2, b3, b4;
    TextView txt;
    static StringBuilder conct = new StringBuilder();
    String contacts = "";
    String delim = ";";
    public static String Name;
    TextView ed;
    int i = 0;
    String[] cellArray;
    DataBaseHelp notasdb = new DataBaseHelp(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.smssend);

        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        b4.setOnClickListener(this);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textnum2);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(smsSentReciver);
        unregisterReceiver(smsSentDelivery);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        smsSentReciver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sms has been sent",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic Fail",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio Off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

                }
            }

        };
        smsSentDelivery = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sms Delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sms not Delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }

        };
        registerReceiver(smsSentReciver, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));
        registerReceiver(smsSentDelivery, new IntentFilter("SMS_DELIVERED"));

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button3:

            Intent a = new Intent(SmsSend.this, MainActivity.class);

            startActivityForResult(a, ResultCode);
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            Intent file = new Intent(SmsSend.this, File_Selecter.class);
            startActivity(file);
            break;

        case R.id.button1:
            if (ed1.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                ed1.setError("First name is required!");
            } else {
                boolean diditwork1 = true;

                try {
                    String Name = ed1.getText().toString();

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

                    String msg = ed2.getText().toString();

                    PendingIntent piSend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                            new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
                    PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                            this, 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);

                    Log.i("SMS", "contacts: " + contacts);

                    String[] cellArray;

                    contacts = conct.toString();

                    cellArray = contacts.split(";");

                    for (int a1 = 0; a1 < cellArray.length; a1++) {

                        // smsManager.sendTextMessage(cellArray[a1].toString(),
                        // null,
                        // msg, piSend, piDelivered);
                    }
                    DataBaseHandler entry = new DataBaseHandler(SmsSend.this);
                    entry.open();

                    entry.entryCreate(Name, msg , contacts);

                    entry.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    diditwork1 = false;
                    String erroe = e.toString();

                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Dang it!");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText(erroe);
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();

                } finally {
                    if (diditwork1) {
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                        d.setTitle("Heck Yeah!");
                        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                        tv.setText("Success");
                        d.setContentView(tv);
                        d.show();
                    }
                }
                ed1.setText("");
                ed2.setText("");
                txt.setText("0");
                conct.delete(0, conct.length());
                break;

            }

        case R.id.button2:

            Log.i("SMS", "Sendlist Size: " + sendlist.size());
              String inputLine = "";
            if (ed1.getText().toString().length() == 0
                    || ed1.getText().toString().length() == 0
        || txt.getText().equals("0")) {
                ed1.setError("First name is required!");
                ed2.setError("Message and contacts are required!");
                txt.setError("Contacts required!");
            } else {
                boolean diditwork1 = true;

                try {
                    String Name = ed1.getText().toString();

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

                    String msg = ed2.getText().toString();

                    PendingIntent piSend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                            new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
                    PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                            this, 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);

                    Log.i("SMS", "contacts: " + contacts);



                    contacts = conct.toString();

                    cellArray = contacts.split(";");

                    for (int a1 = 0; a1 < cellArray.length; a1++) {

                        // smsManager.sendTextMessage(cellArray[a1].toString(),
                        // null,
                        // msg, piSend, piDelivered);

                    }
                    DataBaseHelp entry = new DataBaseHelp(SmsSend.this);
                    entry.open();

                    entry.entryCreate(Name, msg , contacts);

                    entry.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    diditwork1 = false;
                    String erroe = e.toString();

                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Dang it!");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText(erroe);
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();

                } finally {
                    if (diditwork1) {
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                        d.setTitle("Heck Yeah!");
                        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                        tv.setText("Success");
                        d.setContentView(tv);
                        d.show();
                    }
                }
                ed1.setText("");
                ed2.setText("");
                txt.setText("0");
                conct.delete(0, conct.length());






                break;
            }
        }
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == ResultCode) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Intent t = getIntent();
                sendlist = data.getStringArrayListExtra("name");
                if (sendlist != null) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < sendlist.size(); i++) {
                        conct.append(sendlist.get(i).toString());
                        conct.append(delim);
                    }

                }

            }

            i = sendlist.size();
            txt.setText(Integer.toString(i));
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Databasehelp.java

```
package com.example.smscampaign;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.w3c.dom.Comment;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



public class DataBaseHelp{

    public static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME="person_name";
    public static final String KEY_SCALE="scale_person";
    public static final String KEY_CONTACTS="Contacts_person";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="Himani";
     static final String DATABASE_TABLE="peopleTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

    private DbHelper ourHepler;
    private final Context ourContext;
     SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
    public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  " +
                    KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_SCALE + " TEXT NOT NULL ,"  + KEY_CONTACTS + ")"
                    );
            }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public DataBaseHelp(Context c){
        ourContext=c;
    }


    public DataBaseHelp open() throws SQLException{
        ourHepler = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase=  ourHepler.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close()
    {
        ourHepler.close();
    }


    public long entryCreate(String name, String scale , String contacts) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_SCALE, scale);
        cv.put(KEY_CONTACTS, contacts);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv); 

    }


    public ArrayList<String> getData() {

        String[] col= new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_SCALE, KEY_CONTACTS};
        Cursor c=  ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col, null, null, null, null, null);
        String run="";
        int iRow=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iScale=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCALE);
        int iMessage=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTACTS);
        ArrayList<String> newList= new ArrayList<String>();
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
         newList.add(c.getString(iRow)+ " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iScale) + " " + c.getString(iName));
        }

        return newList;
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllContacts()

    { 
        ourDatabase=ourHepler.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT *  FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;

    return ourDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    }



    public String getScale(long l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] col= new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_SCALE , KEY_CONTACTS};
        Cursor c= ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col,KEY_ROWID + "-" + l, null, null, null, null);

        if(c != null){
            c.moveToFirst();
            String scale=c.getString(2);
            return scale;
        }
        return null;
    }


    public String getName(long l)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] col= new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_SCALE , KEY_CONTACTS};
        Cursor c= ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col,KEY_ROWID + "-" + l, null, null, null, null);

        if(c != null){
            c.moveToFirst();
            String name=c.getString(1);
            return name;

        }
        return null;
    }
    public String getContacts(long l)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] col= new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_SCALE ,KEY_CONTACTS};
        Cursor c= ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, col,KEY_ROWID + "-" + l, null, null, null, null);

        if(c != null){
            c.moveToFirst();
            String contacts=c.getString(3);
            return contacts;

        }
        return null;
    }

    public  void updateEntry(long lt, String mName, String mScale ,String mContatcs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          ContentValues cvUpdate=new ContentValues();   
          cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME,mName);
          cvUpdate.put(KEY_SCALE,mScale);
          cvUpdate.put(KEY_CONTACTS,mContatcs );
          ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE,  cvUpdate, KEY_ROWID + "-" + lt, null);
    }


    public void deleteEntry(long ltt) throws SQLException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + ltt,null);

    }
}
```

Comment: its unclear what you want. cut down your code and post only the relevant ones.

Comment: on click on the item in listview..the data from database retrieve by matching the item i.e name in listview and display it in smsSend activity..,such as name,contact number and msg int the respective edittext

Comment: i have already answered that part in your previous question. get the data from database and use intent to pass values between activities. Rest is for you to figure out

Comment: bt in listview i'am displaying only name.,nt the contact number and message..,how to display them too in the edittext in smsSend activity..??

Comment: you can get the name right!. Then write a query to get othere details "select contactnumber,message from talbename where name= "name got from listview item click"". Now you can display the same in next activity

Comment: okk.i have to write this query before the intent pass..??and write it in the variable of the cursor ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49999/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-user3359315)